# Is there a configuration that clears the cache(or perhaps prevents caching) for i18n interpolated strings for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, internationalization, translation, interpolation

```
en.yml - 

hi:
  first_name: "Hi %{name}"
```

```
I18n.t('hi.first_name',{name: "James"}, locale: "en")

--> "Hi James"

I18n.t('hi.first_name',{name: "Nancy"}, locale: "en")

--> "Hi James"
```

Invoking `I18n.reload!` right after an `I18n.t` invocation seems to work but I'm curious about a more efficient/recommended approach.